# A simple example of a ring that is an $A$-module but not an $A$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $A$ and $B$ be commutative rings, and suppose (the underlying group of) $B$ has a structure of $A$-module. "Obviously", that doesn't imply that $B$ gets a structure as an $A$-algebra, but I can't come up with a simple example.

Surely there must be some relatively down-to-earth example, though. Can you help me?

Comment: $A=\mathbb{Z}[x]$, with $x$ acting on $B$ by any additive non-homomorphism?

Comment: @PiotrAchinger you mean abelian group homomorphism but not right $B$-module homomorphism, don't you?

Comment: Take $B$ to be polynomial ring $k[t]$. Take $A$ to be the endomorphism ring of $B$ as
a $k$-vector space. Surely $B$ is an $A$ module, but not an algebra (where would you send the derivative map?).

Comment: I'm not sure why you say $\mathbb{R}$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space but not a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra; any embedding of $\mathbb{C}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ makes $\mathbb{R}$ a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra.  In your situation, $B$ will be an $A$-algebra iff the action of $A$ on $B$ commutes with the action of $B$ on itself.  Equivalently, $B$ is an $A$-algebra iff the action of $a\in A$ coincides with multiplication by $a\cdot 1_B$ in the ring structure of $B$.

Comment: Uh, yes, that's true. Edited to remove that non-example.

Comment: Also, the endomorphism ring of a vector space isn't commutative, so that's also not an example.

Comment: @EricWofsey, there are no $\mathbb C$-algebra structures on $\mathbb R$: such a thing is a map of rings $\mathbb C\to\mathbb R$, which would have to map $i$ to something squaring to $-1$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Oh, oops, of course, I wasn't thinking straight in that first sentence.

Comment: @EricWofsey I think you are right, though not in the way you wanted to be: The isomorphism of the additive groups of $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ carries along the field structure, but the resulting ring structure is not the usual ring structure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $B=\def\QQ{\mathbb Q}\QQ(t)$, which is among other things a rational vector space of countable dimension. In particular, it has a structure of a $\QQ(t_1,t_2)$-module of rank one. But $B$ is not an $\QQ(t_1,t_2)$-algebra in any way, as there are no ring maps $\QQ(t_1,t_2)\to B$.

Comment: @user26857, I have no idea. All I know is that $\mathbb Q(t_1,t_2)$ has countable dimension as a $\mathbb Q$-vector space, so that there exists an isomorphism $\mathbb Q(t_1,t_2)\to B$ of $\mathbb Q$-vector spaces, and then there is a unique way of turning $B$ into a $\mathbb Q(t_1,t_2)$-module so that that map is an isomorphism of $\mathbb Q(t_1,t_2)$-modules.

Comment: I am not being ironic. I don't know what the module structure is, as it depends on the choice of $\mathbb Q$-bases on $\mathbb Q(t_1,t_2)$ and on $\mathbb Q(t)$. My comment above *is* the explanation you wanted.

Comment: WHen someone asks for extra details on my answer, I provide them. You asked for details and I provided them. The person who asked this question, on the other hand, did not, probably because he did not need them — he even accepted the answer, as you can see.

Comment: I do not know what you are asking for, really. Are you asking how to turn $\mathbb Q(t)$ into a $\mathbb Q(t_1,t_2)$-modules so that a givem fixed isomorphism of $\mathbb Q$-vector spaces $\mathbb Q(t)\to\mathbb Q(t_1,t_2)$ becomes an isomorphism of  $\mathbb Q(t_1,t_2)$-modules? If so, I suggest you ask a separate question.

Comment: @user26857, I kindly request that if you intend to communicate with me you do not remove your comments after I have replied to them.

Comment: One way to avoid that urge of yours to remove comments in which you attribute others intentions imagined by you is, simply, not to make them in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

I came up with a counterexample myself: let $A=k[\partial_t]$, and $B=k[t]$, with $A$ acting by differentiation; clearly there is no ring map $\phi:A\to B$ compatible with that action.